# Как записать данные в сессию PHP из формы и сделать переадресацию на другую страницу

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Могу записывать данные в сессии PHP из формы GET. Но у меня ACTION пустой.  и не могу сделать переадресацию.
Проблема такова, что или записываю данные в форму или только переадресация из формы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать и запись данных и переадресацию на другую страницу.

Форма

```
 <form action="" metod="GET">
    <input name="name">
    <input name="surname">
    <input type="submit" name='submit'>
</form>
```

Кнопка

```
<form method="GET">
<div class="cart_btn">
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="product1" value="Кнопка 1" style="font-size:16px;"/>
</form>
```

Comment: header("Location: index.php"); можно сделать, но я не понимаю, как? У меня топорно только через action получается (

Comment: подскажите, вы видите в своем вопросе **php** код?

Comment: Ну вопрос был о PHP сессии. Вроде все логично.

Comment: и? где же ваш PHP код в вашем вопросе?)

Comment: А зачем вам 2 формы на странице? Добавьте всё в одну форму.
Если нужно остаться на той же странице, установите атрибут action="."
И перед формой проверяйте, были ли переданы данные.
Если были - одно действие (например, запись в сессию и переход на другую страницу), если нет - другое (отображение формы).
Для кнопки лучше использовать <button type="submit"></button>